# Automatic Adjustment of brightness, contrast and sharpness of a bitmap image

Tags: java, android, image-processing, bitmapimage

As the title itself suggest everything ... I have to first automatically adjust contrast , brightness and sharpness then if required I have to provide manual adjustment seekbars.

**Is there any library available for automatic adjustment**?

Answer (score 2):

[**OpenCV**](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/) can perform such operations.

[Here is a tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/basic_linear_transform/basic_linear_transform.html) for contrast and brightness.

[OpenCV comes with android ports](http://opencv.org/platforms/android.html), and a quite active community .

A good starting point for you would be [cvEqualizeHist](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/histogram_equalization/histogram_equalization.html), that will adjust brightness and contrast automatically for one channel images (BW).

You can find quite simple methods to find automatic adjustments, but I think that it will still require a bit of work from your side though :).

Answer (score 1):

You can use ImageJ like a library